# Join the result of an SQL query from PostgreSQL to QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql

I want to send an SQL query from a Python script in QGIS to PostgreSQL/PostGIS and get back the result as a table which I then join in QGIS to a shapefile. How do I do that? At the moment I try to achieve the first step: sending an SQL query to PostgreSQL/PostGIS and getting a joinable table back.
It works manually with DB Manager but I don’t know how to translate that into Python. The function seems to be qgis:postgisexecuteandloadsql. But that fails even for a simple SQL:

```
Parameters = { 'DATABASE' : 'HistoPG', 'GEOMETRY_FIELD' : '', 'ID_FIELD' : 'eidied', 'SQL' : 'Select eidied FROM testunion5' }
processing.run("qgis:postgisexecuteandloadsql",  Parameters)
```

The error message is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 18, in 
File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 106, in run
return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
File "C:/PROGRA~2/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 181, in runAlgorithm
raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm.

The table testunion5 actually has a geometry field, but I want just to see a table in QGIS, not a layer. By the way with a geometry field it doesn’t work either:

```
Parameters = { 'DATABASE' : 'HistoPG', 'GEOMETRY_FIELD' : 'geom', 'ID_FIELD' : 'eidied', 'SQL' : 'Select eidied FROM testunion5' }
```

And the actual SQL text which I eventually want to use and which works in DB Manager doesn’t have a geometry field anyway.

I tried also ‘PostgreSQL execute and load SQL’ from the processing toolbox.

[image: PostgreSQL Execute and Load SQL]

The PostGIS log shows the following:

ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """" at character 8
STATEMENT:  SELECT "" FROM (Select eidied FROM testunion5) AS "subQuery_0" LIMIT 0

What can I do to get a table from PostgreSQL/PostGIS which I then can join to a shapefile?
I’m using QGIS 3.10, PostgreSQL 10 and PostGIS 2.5.

The following works in DB Manager:

[image: DB Manager successful]

If I try to repeat that in the console:

```
Parameters = { 'DATABASE' : 'HistoPG', 'GEOMETRY_FIELD' : '', 'ID_FIELD' : 'nummer', 'SQL' : 'Select * FROM testunion' }
processing.run("qgis:postgisexecuteandloadsql", Parameters)
```

I get the following error message in View/Panels/Log Messages/PostGIS:

WARNING    Invalid PostgreSQL layer

View/Panels/Log Messages/Processing has the following messages:

CRITICAL    This layer is invalid!
Please check the PostGIS log for error messages.
CRITICAL    This layer is invalid!
Please check the PostGIS log for error messages.
CRITICAL    There were errors executing the algorithm.

The layer testunion has two fields: nummer (integer, primary key) and geom (geometry).

When I try to define the geometry column, even DB Manager has problems:

[image: DB Manager not successful]

View/Panels/Log Messages/PostGIS:

WARNING    Invalid PostgreSQL layer

Comment: Turn on the statement logging of your PostGIS and check the SQL that DB Manager is sending.

Comment: Statement logging seems to be done only if DB Manager has problems. But with DB Manager there are no problems, so no log. Or what do I misunderstand?

Comment: Statement logging logs all the SQL statements that the database engine receives. Probably DB manager, when it does not have problems, is using some stored metadata about the connection. Remove all old connections and begin from the start, perhaps you get something into the log then.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by „remove all old connections“?
Both the log in C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\data\log and View/Panels/Log Messages/PostGIS don’t show any messages when DB Manager doesn’t have a problems.

Comment: I meant the PostGIS connections that you see in the DB Manager. It is hard to believe that QGIS could add a new SQL query layer by any means without executing and testing that SQL query. I may be wrong still.