# Dissolve with stats in Python for QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, dissolve, statistics

I’m using QGIS 3.10, PostgreSQL 10 and PostGIS 2.5. I want to dissolve within a Python script a shapefile so that the result is dissolved by one field and the number of different values of another field are counted.

I tried different ways:
I used ‘postgisgeoprocessing:dissolvepolygons’:

```
inputfile = "C:/QGIS/Vers1/Results/superClean.shp"
dissfield = "NUMMER"
statatt= "EINZELFNR"

processing.run("postgisgeoprocessing:dissolvepolygons", {'INPUT_LAYER': inputfile,'DISSOLVEALL':False, 'FIELD':dissfield,'SINGLE':False,'COUNT':True,'AREA':False,'STATS':True,'STATSATT':statatt,'SCHEMA':'public','TABLE':'dissolved4','OPTIONS':''})
```

That runs without error, but I don’t know where I would find the result.

I also tried qgis:dissolve

```
inputfile = "C:/QGIS/Vers1/Results/superClean.shp"
outputfile = "C:/QGIS/Vers1/Results/supercleandiss14.shp"
dissfield = "NUMMER"
geometryfield = "geom"

processing.run("qgis:dissolve", {'INPUT':inputfile, 'FIELD': dissfield, 'GEOMETRY': geometryfield, 'KEEP_ATTRIBUTES': False, 'COUNT_FEATURES': True, 'OUTPUT':outputfile})
```

That runs without error and produces a dissolved shapefile. But the attribute table has all fields from the original layer and there is no field which counts the features.

Similar:

```
inputfile = "C:/QGIS/Vers1/Results/superClean.shp"
outputfile = "C:/QGIS/Vers1/Results/supercleandiss15.shp"
dissfield = "NUMMER"
geometryfield = "geom"
statatt= "EINZELFNR"

processing.run("qgis:dissolve", {'INPUT':inputfile, 'FIELD': dissfield, 'GEOMETRY': geometryfield, 'KEEP_ATTRIBUTES': False, 'COUNT_FEATURES': True, 'COMPUTE_STATISTICS': True, 'STATISTICS_ATTRIBUTE': statatt, 'OUTPUT':outputfile})
```

That runs without error and produces a dissolved shapefile. But the attribute table has all fields from the original layer and there is no field which counts the features.

Or with gdal:dissolve:

```
inputfile = "C:/QGIS/Vers1/Results/superClean.shp"
outputfile = "C:/QGIS/Vers1/Results/supercleandiss15.shp"
dissfield = "NUMMER"
geometryfield = "geom"
statatt= "EINZELFNR"

processing.run("gdal:dissolve", {'INPUT':inputfile, 'FIELD': dissfield, 'GEOMETRY': geometryfield, 'KEEP_ATTRIBUTES': False, 'COUNT_FEATURES': True, 'COMPUTE_STATISTICS': True, 'STATISTICS_ATTRIBUTE': statatt, 'OUTPUT':outputfile})
```

That doesn’t produce anything.

So what can I do? I originally tried to do that in PostGIS. So exported the shapefile into PostGIS and then wanted to send an SQL string to PostGIS, get back the result as table and join it to a shapefile. But I failed to send an SQL string to PostGIS and get a table back (See [Join the result of an SQL query from PostgreSQL to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375722/join-the-result-of-an-sql-query-from-postgresql-to-qgis)). I’m open for other ways to achieve in Python for QGIS the following: Union two layers and then apply a group-by query to the union layer. The result should be a table which I then can join to one of the original layers. Shouldn’t actually be that difficult I would have thought.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it out myself. It works with `qgis:aggregate`.
My example:

```
import processing
processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:aggregate")
Parameters = { 'INPUT':'C:/QGIS/Vers1/Results/supercleankurz.shp', 'GROUP_BY': 'NUMMER', 'AGGREGATES': [{
              'input': 'Einzelfl',
              'aggregate': 'count',
              'delimiter': '',
              'name': 'Anzahl',
            'type': 10,
             'length': 255,
             'precision': 0
           }, {
              'input': 'NUMMER',
              'aggregate': 'first_value',
              'delimiter': ',',
              'name': 'Nummer',
            'type': 10,
             'length': 2,
             'precision': 0
           }], 'OUTPUT':'C:/QGIS/Vers1/Results/supercleankurzagg5.shp'}
processing.run("qgis:aggregate", Parameters)
```

It took me a while to find out the syntax for the parameter ‚AGGREGATES‘, but the following link helped:
https://fossies.org/linux/QGIS-final/python/plugins/processing/tests/testdata/qgis_algorithm_tests.yaml
It still doesn’t show all possible parameters, but it helped quite a lot.